# How to redirect old url to new url in MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, redirect

I am facing a problem in redirecting old urls to a new one.
There are many old links on social media and other sources that I need to redirect to the new URL when clicked or else they will display a 404 page not found error.

I have tried adding a new route in RouteConfig.cs file, but when an old link is clicked i get a 404 page not found error.

```html
routes.MapPageRoute("OldArticleRoute", "Article/GetArticle", "~/ViewArticle.aspx");
```

Article/GetArticle - Article is the Controller and GetArticle is the ActionResult.

> http://something.com/ViewArticle.aspx?d=Educational&a_id=32

To:

> http://something.com/Educational/32

Comment: Use IIS Rewrite http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-rewrite-maps-in-url-rewrite-module

Comment: Thank you I did something similar to it. Just not on the server end. I end up adding a page_load method in the view. At the end of the method I am redirecting the old url to the new url using  Response.RedirectPermanent(); That works for me. But thanks for the article. :)

Comment: That sounds like a big change, why don't you move that code to your global cs? easier to maintain and you have it all in one place.